# Videos converted using FFMPEG do not have video duration information

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using FFMPEG to convert uploaded videos to .flv, after conversion the flv video doesn't have information about it's duration. So the user cannot rewind/forward, replay or see a specific part of it. The code is as follows:

```
"ffmpeg -i $srcfile_path -s 320x240 -ar 44100 -b 2048k -r 12 $desfilepath";
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which file container you use?

Comment: Check out: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/288688-ffmpeg-flv-s-won-t-skip-foward  Looks like Ffmpeg may not automatically include all of the necessary metadata.

Comment: Please show your actual ffmpeg command and the complete console output. Without this information we can only make guesses.

Comment: Thanks all of you for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the following command and it worked.

```
"ffmpeg -i $srcfile_path -f flv - | flvtool2 -U stdin $desfilepath"
```

This requires flvtool installed on your system. I am using an FFMPEG and FLVTOOL2 enabled server, so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange, I have been using ffmpeg to convert videos from one format to another without any issues. See example below:

ffmpeg -i input.avi -b:a 192K -b:v 2400 -s hd720 -c:v mpeg2video output.mpg

I am sure you know the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this didn't work while converting a video to flv.